# Lua: Table of functions

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

I am trying to store different functions in a table, but somehow it won't work the way I thought it would. Here is my 'code'

```
fn_table = { aFun1=print, aFun2=self:getSpeedLevel, aFun3=.... }
```

The problem now is that I can do this with the built in functions like `print`, `assert` and so on but it wont work with the other functions I've got.

I get the error: "... function arguments expected near '}'

Is it possible to store these function as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aFun2 = self:getSpeedLevel` is a syntax error and that is what Lua complains about. Try `aFun2 = getSpeedLevel` or `aFun2 = self.getSpeedLevel` (assuming that `self` is a table). The [Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) chapter in the PiL book has more examples of functions being stored in tables.

Comment: To further clarify, the colon notation is really just syntactic sugar over the dot notation. That is, self:getspeed() is really self.getspeed(self)

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment - i was going insane trying to figure out why self.func() does not work while self:func() works...

Comment: By the way, if you want the OO call to work when calling aFun2, you'll need to wrap it as `function(...) self:getSpeedLevel(...) end`.